# How to install hyperledger?

Tags: 16.04

I'm trying to install `hyperledger` in ubuntu 16.04. During installation I got the following error

```
curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/prereqs-ubuntu.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3237  100  3237    0     0   2446      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  2448
chmod u+x prereqs-ubuntu.sh 

./prereqs-ubuntu.sh 

./prereqs-ubuntu.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

./prereqs-ubuntu.sh: line 1:  `!doctype html'

i deleted prereqs-ubuntu.sh file and tried to download using wget
```

When I use `wget` to download file, I got following error

```
`wget https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/prereqs-ubuntu.sh
--2018-05-13 21:51:48--  https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/prereqs-ubuntu.sh
Resolving hyperledger.github.io (hyperledger.github.io)... 185.199.108.153, 185.199.109.153, 185.199.110.153, ...
Connecting to hyperledger.github.io (hyperledger.github.io)|185.199.108.153|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-05-13 21:51:49 ERROR 404: Not Found.`
```

Please guide me to install the `hyperledger` program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in the curl command should be changed to https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/prereqs-ubuntu.sh

Correct command:

`curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/prereqs-ubuntu.sh`

Source: [Hyperledger Composer Docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs)